# Photoshop Save changes directly to Image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing

I have 500+ images that need few sec brushing each, what I will have to do is

- Edit image
- Brush strokes
- Export image
- Replace existing image
- Close the file and hit No I don't wanna save PSD

What I want to do:

- Edit image
- Brush strokes
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save changes to image I am editing
- Close it without PS asking me to save changes to the PSD

It will reduce time required to edit them all to 1/4th. Does Photoshop allow editing of images without dealing with PSD?

**EDIT:** Wolff answered it in comments. If no additional layers are added, I can just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and be done with it, never tested before, because I almost always added layers and thought it was not possible to just save changes.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Which file format are the images you are editing? If I open a PNG and make some edits on the existing layer (*without* adding additional layers) I can just press ctrl + s to save and close the image.

Comment: You *can* add layers, but then you need to merge all layers before hitting Ctrl-s